# check the output for Numeric and Alphabet using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file where i will have IP address and server FQDN names.

example file

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.2.1
kubuntu1.example.com
kubuntu2.example.com
```

i want to write a shell script where i want to get the output of ip address server name without domain name

if file has numeric don't do anything 
else if it has alphabet then get me the output like

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.2.1
kubuntu1
kubuntu2
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

New to shell script so not so sure on regular expressions thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed`. Like this:

```
sed 's/\([a-z][^.]*\).*/\1/' input.file
```

**Explanation:**

I'm using the `s` (substitute) command to "cut off" everything behind the first dot (including the dot) on lines starting with a lowercased letter:

```
s                      The substitute command
/\([a-z][^.]*\).*/     Search pattern
\1                     The replacement pattern.
/                      End of s command
```

The search pattern explained

```
/                      Starting Delimiter
\(                     Start of capturing group
[a-z]                  A lowercased character
[^.]*                  Zero or more non . characters
\)                     End of capturing group
.*                     Rest of the line
/                      Ending delimiter
```

The replacement pattern simply injects the content of the first capturing group `\1`.

---

Btw, if you aren't addicted to typing cryptic characters like me, you can pass the `-r` option to `sed`. Having this you'll usually save most escaping and the command looks cleaner:

```
sed -r 's/([a-z][^.]*).*/\1/' input.file
```

---

Usually domain names won't contain uppercased characters, but pigs can fly ... To get sure you'll capture domains starting with uppercased characters too you should change

```
[a-z]
```

to

```
[a-zA-Z]
```

Comment: Nice! You can also use `-r` to get a nicer command: `sed -r 's/([a-zA-Z]+[^.]*).*/\1/' file` (note I added `A-Z`).

Comment: I don't like nicer commands! ;) I wasn't sure about uppercased characters in domain names. But I guess since domains are case insensitive, uppercased characters may be "allowed" as well.. hmmm..

Comment: Thanks hek2mgl, i am very new to shell and haven't used much of sed,awk and cut, so thanks for the help and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk` command:

```
awk -F '\\.' '!($1+0){$0=$1} 1' file
192.168.1.1
192.168.2.1
kubuntu1
kubuntu2
```

**Explanation:**

```
-F '\\.'   # set input field separator as . (DOT)
!($1+0)    # check if first field is numerically equal to zero (to catch non numeric)
$0=$1      # if yes then set record = first file
1          # default awk action to print whole line
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava this worked and solved my issue, thanks for the expanation.